# Missing Index Feature of SQL Server 2008 Management Studio

Tags: sql-server-2008, query-optimization

While executing the estimated execution plan / actual execution plan, the missing index feature is not showing. How can I enable that ?

I am using SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 0):

The missing indexes feature is on by default. No controls are provided to turn the feature on or off, or to reset any of the tables returned when the dynamic management objects are queried. When SQL Server is restarted, all of the missing index information is dropped.

This feature **can only be disabled if an instance of SQL Server is started by using the -x argument** with the sqlservr command-prompt utility.

[Documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345524%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).